# Conditional JOIN two tables

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to join two tables with a "contingent" joining condition. Lets say I have a `table-1` as

```
ID Col_1 Col_2
1         abc
2   0223  ecfg
3         mnpo
```

Then another table `table-2` as

```
ID col_1 col_2
1          abc
2   0223   ecfg
3          mnpo
```

Now I want to populate ID from `table-2` in `table-1`. Hence I have to join `table-1` and `table-2`

```
SELECT t1.Col_1,t1.Col_2,t2.ID FROM table-1 t1
JOIN table-2 t2
ON t1.Col_1 = t2.Col_1 AND t1.Col_2 = t2.Col_2
```

Now the resultant table-1 should look like

```
ID Col_1  Col_2  ID
 1         abc    1
 2  0223   ecfg   2
 3         mnpo   3
```

However, the above joining logic may not work, as there are two blanks in table-1 and table-2. Joining on blank might lead to erroneous result.

So my question is how can I join these two tables in a fashion like the logic below:

```
 IF Col_1 ISNULL OR Col_1='' THEN t1.Col_2 = t2.Col_2
```

Any clue would be appreciated. Can `CASE` statement be used in `JOIN`?

Comment: This is not correct and wrong approach, as well as joining identical tables. Concept of joins is different, than just filtering extra spaces in single tables

Answer (score 0):

Add `WHERE` in your query.

```sql
SELECT t1.Col_1,t1.Col_2,t2.ID FROM table-1 t1
JOIN table-2 t2
ON t1.Col_1 = t2.Col_1 AND t1.Col_2 = t2.Col_2
WHERE t1.Col_1 IS NOT NULL AND t1.Col_1 != ''
```

Comment: this would may not suffice. Only cases when `t1.Col_1` is not blank then only your logic would work.